# Java TextArea crowding out Button

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am using javafx and trying to get a search button on top of my window. I am using an HBox to add the area and button, but the area is too wide. I can fix this by hardcoding a minimum size for the button, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way that would help me learn javafx.

[search bar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06uvK.png)

```
    TextArea searchArea = new TextArea("Search");
    TextArea resultsArea = new TextArea("Results");
    Button searchButton = new Button("Search");
    HBox topBox = new HBox(searchArea, searchButton);

    searchButton.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    searchArea.setMinHeight(10);
    topBox.setMaxHeight(10);
```

Comment: Try this [tutorial]{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html} for more layout possibilities.

Comment: This can be tried: use a grid pane with one row and two columns, instead of a hbox. Set column constraints for the grid pane - this allows the percentage of the width of the grid pane used for each of the widgets (text area and the button). Also, you can use a separator to control space between the widgets. Why are you using a text area for a search area (I was of the impression it is to be a text field)?

Comment: If setting a min-width for the `Button` works, I don't understand the problem?

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks, I will use the answer by Zephyr but I'll also use the TextField instead of TextArea, I am new to javafx so I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the 'minWidth' property of the `Button` to use the "preferred size."

This will determine the optimal width of the `Button` (based on the contents, which in your case is the text "Search") and insures it never shrinks below that:

```
searchButton.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

This will accomplish your goal without having to hard-code a specific size for the button.

Comment: Thanks, though why did Region.USE_PREF_SIZE work when searchButton.getPrefWidth() not work? Are these different things?

Comment: That is actually a good question. `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE` is simply a constant for `-1.0D / 0.0`. So, it's the equivalent of using `searchButton.setMinWidth(-1.0D / 0.0). When running `searchButton.getPrefWidth()`, you get `-1.0`. Somehow, dividing by 0 is what does the trick. It's a mystery to me.

Comment: Coincidentally, using `searchButton.setMinWidth(searchButton.getPrefWidth() / 0.0)` DOES work...